# Linux so convention: is the .so link intended to come from dev packages?

Tags: symlink, shared-library, dynamic-linking, conventions

On my Ubuntu jammy Linux PC, after installing the libuv1 package (`apt-get install libuv1`), I noticed that there was a file, named `libuv.so.1.0.0` and a symbolic link to it, named `libuv.so.1`:

```
$ find /usr -name "libuv.so*" 2>/dev/null
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1
$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     14 Jan 15  2022 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1 -> libuv.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 198744 Jan 15  2022 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1.0.0
$
```

From probably incomplete understandings, I was expecting there to also be a `libuv.so` symbolic link, something like `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so -> libuv.so.1`.

I've seen this mix of presence/absence of the `.so` symlink, but never properly understood if there was a reason/convention behind that.

I thought I might have stumbled into The Answer in [this blog post](https://dmerej.info/blog/post/symlinks-and-so-files-on-linux/). If I correctly understand the content of that post:

- semantic-versioned .so files, e.g. `libfoo.so.1.0.0` are the real files that symlinks ultimately resolve to; they are compiled with the `soname` option, e.g. `gcc -I . foo.c -shared -Wl,-soname=libfoo.so.1 -o libfoo.so.1.0.0`.
- Because of the use of the `soname` option, when a binary is compiled with `-lfoo` (in an environment where there exists `libfoo.so -> libfoo.so.1 -> libfoo.so.1.0.0` links), the compiler/linker will look for `libfoo.so`, which resolves to `libfoo.so.1.0.0`, which has been compiled with `-soname=libfoo.so.1`, therefore the binary will know that it needs `libfoo.so.1` at runtime.
  (i.e. `readelf -d` on the binary would output something like `0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED) Shared library: [libfoo.so.1]`)
- When the binary is run in an environment with only `libfoo.so.1 -> libfoo.so.1.0.0` (i.e no `libfoo.so -> libfoo.so.1`), it will run fine: because of the above, it will be looking for `libfoo.so.1`, not `libfoo.so`.

*My conjecture*: this seems to imply that only when you are *developing* with a shared library will you need the `libfoo.so` symlink because of the need to specify the `-l` flag, e.g. `g++ use-foo.cpp -o ./use-foo -lfoo`. In this case, the use of `-lfoo` means the compiler/linker will be looking for `libfoo.so`, not `libfoo.so.*`.

The above seems to bear out with compiling a simple hello-world example that links dynamically, and also inspecting what is installed with the `libuv1` vs. `libuv1-dev` packages:

```
$ apt-file list libuv1 | grep so.*
libuv1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1
libuv1: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so.1.0.0
$
$ apt-file list libuv1-dev | grep so.*
libuv1-dev: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuv.so
$
```

But then a wrench was thrown into the works, when I found files, *not symlinks*, like `libmemusage.so` (I'm just picking one example, at random):

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmemusage.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 18904 Sep 25 07:45 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmemusage.so
```

My question is: **is there one comprehensive rule that describes the relationship between `libfoo.so`, `libfoo.so.x`, and `libfoo.so.x.y.z`, when and why any specific combination of them should exist, and when and why any of them should be files vs. symbolic links?**

Is there any case where I, as a non-developer Linux PC user, am supposed to create any "missing" symbolic link (as in the very beginning of the question, where I saw `libuv.so.1` but not `libuv.so`)? (Context to this question: in the past, I've been asked to create a "missing" `libfoo.so` symlink, when `libfoo.so.x` and/or `libfoo.so.x.y.z` existed, but I never properly understood why this was necessary, other than a half-baked notion that "there's always a bunch of `.so` files, and they seem to have "corresponding" `.so.x` and `.so.x.y.z` files).

---

(I can see the case that this question might belong at Stack Overflow: it's tangentially related to programming, but I ultimately thought that the heart of the question was about Unix/Linux conventions. But please let me know if it's certain that this question is better suited for Stack Overflow.)

Comment: Most of this is covered in https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-sharedlibs.html (your conjecture in particular is the fifth paragraph). If you can give a specific case of when you were asked to make a symlink, we might be able to tell why that was needed instead of installing the dev package.

Comment: @muru "If you can give a specific case of when you were asked to make a symlink" -- the specifics are lost to years-past history, unfortunately. I will give your link a read, though, it looks like it addresses my question. I _suspect_ that those who asked me to create the symlink in the past also had somewhat half-baked understandings of the relevant conventions, and might have just been winging it, and I likely just followed along, assuming expertise/correctness on their part.

Comment: Ah well. One possible explanation is that it wasn't them but the people who made the corresponding packages who were winging it - you may have installed a package from some third party repo (or something like that - not a package from the official repos anyway), so you had to make the symlink because the developers didn't.